# How to show something while refreshing instead of default white page with nextjs?

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend, refresh, white-framework

For example, if you refresh facebook.com, while refreshing you will still see nav bar, how to do that?

I have tried with Router.events.on and off to get loading time, but still have white page on refresh

Answer (score 0):

You need persistent [layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#single-shared-layout-with-custom-app).

Putting the following code in your `_app` file will cause the layout to not remount on every page change.

```
// pages/_app.js

import Layout from '../components/layout'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

The idea would be to put `header`, `footer` etc. in your layout and the rest of the main body will change.

Comment: Nope, there is again a white blank page immediately after you click refresh.